# Auto reloading div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using below code but div won't auto refresh after 5 seconds,

Can anyone tell me what is the issue with my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
Some content
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#test").load();
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've to provide URL to the `load()`, it cannot get the URL magically

Comment: If you want to load new text dynamically from any page then first give the URL of that page into load().
or
If you want any static text then just use this  $("#test").text("static text"); inside setInterval.

Comment: $("#test").load('your url'); should be there

Comment: I added load('http://myurl.com/page'); but it just refreshes the page and doesnt load properly

Answer (score 0):

you need to set parameter for load.

please check at here:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function(){} );
```

Comment: i did that, but it refreshes my whole page and then doesnt load correctly

Comment: .load not refresh page, you may have problem in other part of your code

Comment: could you show me what you would do? to refresh a div every 5 secs?

Comment: you code it right. if you have it uploaded in somewhere i will help you (it help me to check your code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead. See if it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get( "http://some-url.net/", function( data ) {
            $("#test").html(data);
        }, "html");
    }, 5000);
});
```